# Append to an Outlook Appointment through Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a table with a date column.
If the date for that record is a future date I want to create an appointment in Outlook if one isn't already there.
If an appointment already exists I want to add a line to the body of the appointment.

My code will create the appointment if one doesn't exist.

How do I append to an existing appointment where the subject lines match?

```vb
Private Sub Process_InSeason_Click()
    Dim olobj As Outlook.Application
    Dim oloappt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim myOptionalAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim PackNum As String
    Dim Desc As String
    Dim Brand As String
    Dim rs As Dao.Recordset
    Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryEventSetup")
    Set olobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oloappt = olobj.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    Set myOptionalAttendee = oloappt.Recipients.Add("Email@emailaddress.com")
    
    myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Save records and turn on Error Control
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    On Error GoTo Add_Err
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Validate if Markdown End date is future date
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    rs.MoveFirst
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
    
    Appt = rs.Fields("Markdown End Date").Value
    Appt = DateSerial(Year(Appt), Month(Appt), Day(Appt))
    Appt = Appt + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)
    
    PackNum = rs.Fields("Pack_Number")
    Desc = rs.Fields("Description")
    Brand = rs.Fields("Brand Offer")
    
    'Deleteappt
    
        With oloappt
                '.RequiredAttendees = myOptionalAttendee
                .Subject = "Remove Markdowns for all Offers"
                .Body = "" & PackNum & "  " & Desc & "  " & Brand & " Please update page number to 851 for all markdown 6 prefixes"
                .MeetingStatus = 1
                .ResponseRequested = True
                .Start = Appt
                .Duration = 10
                .ReminderSet = True
                .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 1440
                .Save
                '.Display
                .Send
                .Close (olSave)
        End With
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
        MsgBox "Markdown End Date(s) have been added to your Calendar"
    End If
    'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'End process and clean up
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set oloappt = Nothing
    Set olobj = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set myOptionalAttendee = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Error validation
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Add_Err:
    MsgBox "oops error found " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub
```

Comment: in the search bar above type in: vba outlook appointment

Comment: @Sorceri not really helpful. I've done a lot of searches but not finding exactly what I'm looking for which is why I asked the question. Do you have something specifically in search you found? Can you link it?

Comment: Will these help https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/editing-outlook-task-appt-from-access-vba.182356/, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/using-vba-to-find-search-for-and-edit-a/8ae64eea-f24a-4008-b191-262831cc9f83?auth=1

Comment: One possible method of finding whether there is an existing item to append to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71444905/outlook-vba-modification-request-for-a-removeduplicates-script-keep-the-copy