# Remove duplicate items keeping the copy that has been read

Tags: vba, outlook, duplicates

The code below removes duplicate items from a folder in Outlook.

My request:

If two exact items exist, keep the copy that has been read, and delete the copy that has not been read.

```vb
Sub RemoveDuplicateItems()
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim strKey As String

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Select a source folder
    Set objFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder

    If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        For i = objFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
       
            Set objItem = objFolder.Items.Item(i)

            Select Case objFolder.DefaultItemType
                'Check email subject, body and sent time
                Case olMailItem
                    strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.Body & "," & objItem.SentOn
                'Check appointment subject, start time, duration, location and body
                Case olAppointmentItem
                    strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.Start & "," & objItem.Duration & "," & objItem.Location & "," & objItem.Body
                'Check contact full name and email address
                Case olContactItem
                    strKey = objItem.FullName & "," & objItem.Email1Address & "," & objItem.Email2Address & "," & objItem.Email3Address
                'Check task subject, start date, due date and body
                Case olTaskItem
                    strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.StartDate & "," & objItem.DueDate & "," & objItem.Body
            End Select
    
            strKey = Replace(strKey, ", ", Chr(32))

            'Remove the duplicate items
            If objDictionary.Exists(strKey) = True Then
                objItem.Delete
            Else
                objDictionary.Add strKey, True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save `EntryId` to delete an item with data previously saved in the dictionary.

Check each item instead of assuming the type will be the default type for the folder.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicateUnreadItems()

    ' Remove duplicates, with a preference for unread items
    
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim strKey As String
    
    Dim dictionaryItem As Object

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Select a source folder
    'Set objFolder = Session.PickFolder
    Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")
    
    If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
    
       For i = objFolder.Items.count To 1 Step -1
       
            Set objItem = objFolder.Items.Item(i)
            
            Select Case objItem.Class
            
                'Check email subject, body and sent time
                Case olMail
                    strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.Body & "," & objItem.SentOn
                
                'Check appointment subject, start time, duration, location and body
                Case olAppointment
                    strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.Start & "," & objItem.duration & "," & objItem.Location & "," & objItem.Body
                    
                'Check contact full name and email address
                Case olContact
                    strKey = objItem.fullName & "," & objItem.Email1Address & "," & objItem.Email2Address & "," & objItem.Email3Address
                    
                'Check task subject, start date, due date and body
                Case olTask
                    strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.startDate & "," & objItem.DueDate & "," & objItem.Body
                    
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print "Unexpected class: " & objItem.Class
                    'MsgBox "Unexpected class: " & objItem.Class
                    'objItem.Display
                    GoTo skipClass
                    
            End Select
              
            strKey = Replace(strKey, ", ", Chr(32))

            'Debug.Print objItem.Subject
            'Remove the duplicate items
            If objDictionary.Exists(strKey) = True Then
                 
                Debug.Print objItem.Subject
                
                If objItem.UnRead = True Then
                    Debug.Print "objItem.Delete"
                    objItem.Delete
                Else
                    ' Replace existing without further verification
                    Set dictionaryItem = Session.GetItemFromID(objDictionary(strKey))
                    Debug.Print "dictionaryItem.Delete"
                    dictionaryItem.Delete
                    objDictionary(strKey) = objItem.EntryID
                End If
                
            Else
                objDictionary.Add strKey, objItem.EntryID
                
            End If
            
skipClass:
       Next i
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
End Sub
```